# Same correlated variable value should not pick by another user how to handle it in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have scenario in a page we have list of uuid's which will be changing every time count wise and details wise.

So same uuid should not pick by another user at time while running the test for multiple users for certain duration.

How to handle this in JMeter? can any one help me in it?

I tried random logic but we have probability some where in test we will get same uuid will be passed 2 different users.

tried random.shuffle() as well.

Is there any where we can get user instance in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

Random != unique, if you need to guarantee the uniqueness the easiest option is:

1. Extract the UUIDs using a suitable Post-Processor and write them into a CSV file somewhere in the [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)
2. In the "normal" Thread Group you can use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read the UUIDs from the file. Given you set "Recycle on EOF" to `False` and "Stop thread on EOF" to `True`, this way each virtual user will pick the next UUID on each iteration, when the all UUIDs will be used your test will stop.

Comment: But my values will be changing during the test so one time updating to file and using it will not work ? i tried the above option as well.
Is there any way we can get which user instance is being executed in jmeter?

Comment: You can get it using [__threadNum() function]. If you want 1st user to use 1st UUID, 2nd user to use 2nd UUID, etc. you can use [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) like `${__V(your-var-able-name-here_${__threadNum},)}`. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: Can i directly use this in my script. like ${__V(C_uuid_${__thresdNum},)}
same i tried in JSR223 postprocessor (groovy) it retuning null value.

Comment: You can, given you can property type the function name. [Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into Groovy scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as only first occurrence will be cached and stored in the subsequent iterations, you should use something like `vars.get('C_uuid_' + ctx.getThreadNum())`, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article to learn more about what do these `vars` and `ctx` guys mean